# sudo apt-get update Not working

Tags: raspbian, apt, sudo

Pi connected via ssh remotely. This is the log running

```
 pi@raspberrypi:/etc $ sudo apt-get update Err
 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie InRelease                   
 Err ht**://raspbian.mirror.net.in jessie InRelease                    
 Err ht**://mirrordirector.raspbian.org jessie Release.gpg             
 Cannot initiate the connection to mirrordirector.raspbian.org:80
 (2001:41c9:1:3ce::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP:
 2001:41c9:1:3ce::11 80] Err ht**://raspbian.mirror.net.in jessie
 Release.gpg         Unable to connect to raspbian.mirror.net.in:http:
 0% [Connecting to archive.raspberrypi.org (93.93.128.230)]
```

Comment: Change the mirror in the sources file ([Source](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/103555/149416))

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had proxy problems. fixed by pointing to proxy server.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like it's trying to use IPv6. I bet your connection doesn't have IPv6 (yet).

Make a config file that disables IPv6.

Run the command `sudoedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99force-ipv4`, put `Acquire::ForceIPv4 "true";` in it then save it.

If you want a temporary solution, run `apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update` instead of just `apt-get update` to make it use IPv4.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have internet connection.
Make sure you are connected and try again.