# Could not connect to raspbian.raspberrypi.org in raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspbian-stretch

sorry i am a newbie, when i want to `sudo apt-get update` i can't connect to raspbian.raspberrypi.org, and when i click the link is not responding, but when i use my handphone to acces the link with vpn it is worked, should i use vpn on raspberry pi, and how to use vpn in raspberry pi

```
Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch InRelease               
  Could not connect to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.128.193), connection timed out
Err:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease                  
  Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:88:26::1). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:13:0:6). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:82:1000:13:0:7). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:82:1000:13:0:6). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:13:0:5). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:13:0:8). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:82:1000:13:0:5). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:82:1000:13:0:9). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:13:0:7). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.135.188), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.130.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.128.230), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.130.214), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.128.133), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (46.235.227.11), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (46.235.231.111), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.128.211), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.130.104), connection timed out
Reading package lists... Done                                          
W: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Could not connect to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to raspbian.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.128.193), connection timed out
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/stretch/InRelease  Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:88:26::1). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:13:0:6). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:82:1000:13:0:7). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:82:1000:13:0:6). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:13:0:5). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:13:0:8). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:82:1000:13:0:5). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:82:1000:13:0:9). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (2a00:1098:0:80:1000:13:0:7). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.135.188), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.130.39), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.128.230), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.130.214), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.128.133), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (46.235.227.11), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (46.235.231.111), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.128.211), connection timed out Could not connect to archive.raspberrypi.org:80 (93.93.130.104), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recently `raspbian.raspberrypi.org` has become slow and unreliable.
This affects many people, but not all. In my case it often took several tries and hours to update.

I solved this by replacing `raspbian.raspberrypi.org` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` with  a local mirror;
in my case

```
deb http://raspbian.melbourneitmirror.net/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

although you should select a local mirror from https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors/

This also works with **Stretch**  which is also slow since the release of Buster (although using the original `/etc/apt/sources.list` for Stretch).

> PS Do not change `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list` which appears to be necessary for kernel/firmware updates.

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue. I noticed that it resolved to an IPv6 address vs an IPv4.  I have IPv6 blocked on my firewall.  I disabled IPv6 temporary and everything worked just fine.

By the way here's the command to do that.
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1

Answer (score 2):

You try to update your **Raspbian Stretch** operating system. If being a newbie I strongly suggest to use up to date **Raspbian Buster**.

Then you try to update the operating system without an internet connection. You must have it before doing updates, upgrades and installations. The simplest is to connect the RasPi with an ethernet cable to your internet router. This works mostly out of the box without any additional configuration. Otherwise you can look at [Wireless connectivity](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/README.md).

And no, you should not use **vpn** as long as you have essential connection problems.