# sudo apt-get update and packge install not working

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye InRelease
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
Err:2 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian bullseye InRelease
  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 93.93.135.141 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 93.93.128.193 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/dists/bullseye/InRelease  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 93.93.135.141 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping raspbian.raspberrypi.org
PING mirrordirector.raspbian.org (93.93.128.193) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193 (93.93.128.193): icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=233 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193 (93.93.128.193): icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=260 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193 (93.93.128.193): icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=340 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193 (93.93.128.193): icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=239 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193 (93.93.128.193): icmp_seq=5 ttl=53 time=220 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193 (93.93.128.193): icmp_seq=6 ttl=53 time=293 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193 (93.93.128.193): icmp_seq=7 ttl=53 time=191 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193 (93.93.128.193): icmp_seq=8 ttl=53 time=247 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193 (93.93.128.193): icmp_seq=9 ttl=53 time=263 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193 (93.93.128.193): icmp_seq=10 ttl=53 time=243 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193 (93.93.128.193): icmp_seq=11 ttl=53 time=238 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193 (93.93.128.193): icmp_seq=12 ttl=53 time=279 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193 (93.93.128.193): icmp_seq=13 ttl=53 time=215 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193 (93.93.128.193): icmp_seq=14 ttl=53 time=254 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193 (93.93.128.193): icmp_seq=15 ttl=53 time=216 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193 (93.93.128.193): icmp_seq=16 ttl=53 time=223 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193 (93.93.128.193): icmp_seq=17 ttl=53 time=358 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193 (93.93.128.193): icmp_seq=18 ttl=53 time=249 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193 (93.93.128.193): icmp_seq=19 ttl=53 time=200 ms
64 bytes from 93.93.128.193 (93.93.128.193): icmp_seq=20 ttl=53 time=263 ms
^C
--- mirrordirector.raspbian.org ping statistics ---
22 packets transmitted, 20 received, 9.09091% packet loss, time 21088ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 190.909/251.137/357.678/40.799 ms
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ wget http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/bullseye/InRelease
--2022-04-26 11:39:32--  http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/dists/bullseye/InRelease
Resolving raspbian.raspberrypi.org (raspbian.raspberrypi.org)... 93.93.128.193, 2a00:1098:0:80:1000:75:0:3
Connecting to raspbian.raspberrypi.org (raspbian.raspberrypi.org)|93.93.128.193|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 14976 (15K)
Saving to: ‘InRelease.1’

InRelease.1                                                 100%[========================================================================================================================================>]  14.62K  --.-KB/s    in 0.004s

2022-04-26 11:39:33 (3.77 MB/s) - ‘InRelease.1’ saved [14976/14976]

pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

Comment: Yes... Millwas , Itried but it didn't work

Comment: What I don't understand.
When I ping or use wget to the raspberry server it works

but when I tried to update or install packages it does not work at all.
I want to install some packages

Comment: Are you using an HTTP proxy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not connect to raspbian.raspberrypi.org in raspberry pi 3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/103539/could-not-connect-to-raspbian-raspberrypi-org-in-raspberry-pi-3)

Comment: I'm not using any proxy. However, after many tries, I have run sudo apt-get clean and it fixed on one of my pi.

But I'm checking on the others, I'll try on the lite OS version to see if fixes the issue,

@Thanks